# Nodejs callback function read and write global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

this is my code.

```
            while(!pause && (tmp = sqls.pop())) {
            pool.request().query(tmp.sql)
            .then(rs => {
                if (tmp.cnt !== rs.rowsAffected[0]) {
                    console.log('insert is not completive');
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(tmp);
                console.error(error);
                sqls.push(tmp);
                // If an TimeoutError occurred, pause the read stream
                if(error.name === "TimeoutError") {
                    pause = true;
                    setTimeout(()=>{pause = false;}, 1000);
                }

            })
            }
```

I want to use the database query callback function to read the variable `tmp`,  and modify the variable `pause`.

But as you know, the tmp object in callback function is `undefined` while before query it's {sql:"xxx", cnt:60}.(I have tried debug and log out it), also I cannot modify the global variable `pause`.

I have read some related questions, most solutions are try to make variables as parameters to callback function but I cannot modify this library code, and this solution cannot modify gloabal variables, too.

Also there are solutions about use a `windows` object(for browser) to refer to a variable, but I am not understand why the callback function can access `windows` object. And my code is just a standalone file running on nodejs.

Do you have any idea about how to read and write the gloabal variable in callback function?

Comment: Your `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers are scheduled asynchronously and thus can NEVER run during your  `while` loop.  So, either your `while` loop will be an infinite loop or it will stop when `sqls.pop()` runs out of data, but it will never stop because `pause` is set because the code that changes `pause` can't run during your `while` loop.

Comment: So, all this asking about global variables is probably not really the operative part of what's wrong here.  You need to learn how asynchronous operations work.  If you want to serialize your async operations so you run one, get its result, do some checks on it and then decide if you want to run the next one, then you need to either use `await` or redesign how your loop works to not use `for` or `while`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you jfrined. This is and produce and consumption problem, the sqls is generated from io stream, I have to manage the stream in order to keep it "synchrone" to asynchronous database operations.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not enough info/detail for us to know what to suggest.

Comment: @jfriend00 actually the while loop is added to help me serialize the reading and querying(but not succeeded :(  

The complete code is read from a stream -> get lots of data to be inserted into database -> generate sqls -> querying.

And the read stream is to fast for database to persist it's data, causing RequestTimeoutError. I am trying to solve this problem

Comment: Then, perhaps you should describe the WHOLE problem in your question with enough details that we can understand and be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: thanks for your help, I am clear now. I should not control the io stream in an async operation's callback.  I have redesign the processure, monitor and check the db pool state before further read.  Thanks again~